# Error installing rtl8812au-dkms package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dkms, rtl

Trying to install the package for my usb wireless and I get the following error and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
    ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg for kernel 4.10.0-30-generic (x86_64)
 Fri 11 Aug 15:28:53 BST 2017
 make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build  modules
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic'
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_security.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_debug.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_io.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_vht.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_rf.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_recv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_ap.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_iol.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_btcoex.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_beamforming.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/rtw_odm.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
 /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c: In function ‘rtw_android_priv_cmd’:
 /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:577:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘is_compat_task’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (is_compat_task()) {
       ^
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o] Error 1
 Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build' failed
 make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic'
 Makefile:1459: recipe for target 'modules' failed
 make: *** [modules] Error 2
DKMSKernelVersion: 4.10.0-30-generic
Date: Fri Aug 11 15:29:12 2017
DuplicateSignature: dkms:rtl8812au-dkms:4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu2:/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:577:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘is_compat_task’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
Package: rtl8812au-dkms 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu2
PackageVersion: 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu2
SourcePackage: rtl8812au
Title: rtl8812au-dkms 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu2: rtl8812au kernel module failed to build
```

Comment: Are you installing this from source code, or via the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, installing from Ubuntu repositories. But I can't help. It's failing when trying to install the rtw_android.o file. Which it shouldn't do as I'm installing on Ubuntu not andriod

Answer (score 1):

Get the newer version of rtl8812au at https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/tree/driver-4.3.14